# Rails Javascript if else condition using variable from Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

View

```
<%= link_to "Link", {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"}, 
            :update => "Ajaxcall", :remote => true %>
```

Controller

```
  def AjaxView
    @vars= Var.find(:all,:conditions => { :varName=> "one" },:select=>(params[:col]))
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :layout=>false }
    end
  end
```

AjaxView.js.erb

```
   if ( (<%= col %>) == "colName") {
     $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
   }
   else
   {
     $("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
   }
```

Issue here is this Variable "col" doesn't get its exact value in AjaxView.js.erb file, and my If else condition doesn't get executed. What am i missing here ?

Comment: side note: the modern approach is to get JSON (not JS code) and let JS (in the client) update the view.

Comment: @amit don't replicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712852/ruby-if-condition-not-working-properly-in-javascript-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if ( @col.to_s == "colName") {
      $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
     }
      elsif ( @col.to_s == "colName1")
     {
     $("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `col` isn't assigned in `AjaxView.js.erb`. I think you meant to write it as `params[:col]`.

Also the double quotes around `var` should be single quotes, to play nice with the surrounding double quotes.

Comment: is tried with params[:col] in my if condition, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
{:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"}
```

This is not how you build a url for link_to.

What's the route to access the `AjaxView` method?
It should be something like: `link_to "Link", AjaxView_resources_path(:col => "colname")`.

And in your controller, you need to set an instance variable `@col = params[:col]` to be able to use it in your view.

ps: your should name your method ajax_view instead of AjaxView.

Comment: Thanks @Robin for your reply, when I put     "( @ col = params[:col])"   in controller  and in AjaxView.js.erb when I run this     " (if ( (<%= @ col %>) == "colName"))", it still didn't worked.

Comment: The thing is, with the way you build your link, I don't even know how your action gets executed...

Comment: lot of people have doubted that, some even suggested that I should start using form instead of link, there are blogs written on this, but somehow i was able to run this without any issue. And it works for me, only issue here that I am facing now is to try with multiple options, and for that I have to run if condition in .js.erb file, if you could help me running this, I will be really thankful. I am almost done with my work.

Comment: Also, AjaxView_resources_path(:col => "colname") is same as  {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"} just the way of writing is different, whatever I am writing in curly bracket goes as a HTML input.

Comment: I dont think it is... How is rails supposed to know about which controller to use? Also, I can't see why you would need a form. A link is fine in this case.

Comment: Controller is mapped using same name of AjaxView.js.erb file, in controller def AjaxView and javascript file name is same. And Action name I am explictly specifying in my request as :action

Comment: I was talking about this link: `<%= link_to "Link", {:action => "AjaxView",:col => "colname"}...`. But anyways, if you dont want to change that, dont. Try logging stuff in your controller and in your `AjaxView.js.erb` with `console.log` or just `alert()`.

Comment: This doesn't work,  @col = params[:col], something wrong with this. alert placed in js file stops coming. when I run alert(@col);

Comment: You need alert("<%= @col %>")