# Ruby if condition not working properly in javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Controller:

```
def AjaxView
  @vars= Var.find(:all,:conditions => { :varName=> "one" },:select=>(params[:col]))
  @col = params[:col]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout=>false }
  end
end
```

AjaxView.js.erb

```
  if('<%= @col %>' == 'colName'){
    $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>");
  } else if('<%= @col %>' == 'colName2'){
    $("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var1")) %>");
  }
```

View Partial:

_var.html.erb

```
 <%= @vars[0].colName %>
```

_var1.html.erb

```
  <%= @vars[0].colName2 %>
```

If I change this code

```
$("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>");
```

to **alert("hi_one");** and

```
$("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var1") %>");
```

to **alert("hi_two");**

it works fine.

but when I put the above code, it runs both the code each time, not sure why, is it compiling it or what ? and whats the way out?

Render Output:

Rendered test/_var.html.erb (16.0ms)
Rendered test/AjaxView.js.erb (19.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms

ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: colName):
    1: <%= @ vars[0].col %>

Javascripty output in Firebug is 500 error

Comment: DOM element IDs cannot be numbers and be valid HTML.

Comment: David, I changed it but I am still getting same issue

Comment: Does it render anything?

Comment: Yes, its rendering both the scripts each time, which generates a conflict ActionView::Template::Error (missing attribute: colName):

Comment: Please add the rendered output to the question.

Comment: as per your ajaxview.js, there is a syntax error 
`<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var") %>` should be <%= `escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>` and `<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var1") %>`
should be `<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var1")) %>`

Comment: @NarenSisodiya thanks for pointing, it was typing mistake while putting up the question, I have edited it in the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton When I chose option first column, then second column code also get rendered, which generated a conflict, saying that missing attribute
which is correct since I am calling a partial which will be using this code , I have added View code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your condition `if('<%= @col %>' == 'colName')` is **client-side** JavaScript.

What this means is that in

```
if('<%= @col %>' == 'colName'){
    $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>");
} else if('<%= @col %>' == 'colName2'){
    $("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var1")) %>");
}
```

both `render :partial` calls are executed **server-side** in order for Rails to render the template but then when the generated JavaScript executes client-side the logic determines which `.text` call executes. This means that the contents of both partials must be valid in both scenarios (even the one that eventually isn't going to be used.)

To fix it, either include both `colName` and `colName2` in your `:select` or change the `if` to be server-side so that you then respond with just one 1 of the `.text` lines. e.g.

```
<% if @col == 'colName' %>
  $("#3").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var")) %>");
<% elsif @col == 'colName2' %>
  $("#2").text("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "var1")) %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, it was a nice explanation. And it did resolves my issue.